# Hibernate OneToMany Insert fails Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Stuck with a odd Cannot insert the value NULL, Insert Fails Exception, Thnaks in advance for all the help.

Below is my mapping:

Entity Class Role:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
public Set<Feature> getFeatures() {
    return features;
}

public void setFeatures(Set<Feature> features) {
    this.features = features;
}
```

Feature Entity Class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false)
public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

Error:

```
 Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ROLE_ID', table 'FEATURE'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1481) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
```

And yes, i have called the getter setters to set the parent child object relations  appropriately

Comment: Post the code which is doing save operation (service or dao) please.

Comment: Please post your code to enable us to help you. Else its just shooting in the dark and guess work

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false)  said that the column can not be stored if it is null, so probably in the moment that you are inserting the record this relationship is null, which is forbidden by the constraint. but remember ID should have a value, beside add the parent-child relationship, the error make me think that @Id of the parent is not set in the moment you tried to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this. Problem was with two different EntityManager contexts that were conflicting, although the exception relates nothing to what the problem was.